# show to pass predefined data from model to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have some predefined data in the form of array which I want to access into my views. 
I'm using the following approach for this purpose.
I define a method in model, which returns an array.

```
//function in my model calss of cars.

public function colors(){
  return ['white', 'blue','gray'];
}
```

When I call this method like that :

```
$cars->colors();
```

here is the code that i wants to use in my view file

```
@foreach($car->colors() as $color)
  <p> {!!$color!!}</p>
@endforeach
```

It shows me the following error : **Relationship method must return an object of type**

What's the proper way to handle such type of situation if I want an array or any data from my model object or alternate way.

Comment: Can you show the code of the view that uses this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Eloquent's accessors to add custom attribute to your model - see more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

In your case, the following should do the trick:

```
class Car extends Model {
  public function getColorsAttribute(){
    return ['white', 'blue','gray'];
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to access the list of colors with:

```
foreach ($car->colors as $color) {
  ...
}
```

The error you're getting seems to be related to something else though - usually it means you're trying to eagerly load a non-existing relation. Make sure you don't have any calls to `with('colors')` on your Car model.